# pyInstaller: Pack binary executable inside project's executable to run

Tags: python, ffmpeg, anaconda, pyinstaller, anaconda3

**TLDR;**

I would like to pack the `ffmpeg` executable inside my own executable. Currently I am getting

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
Skipping ./testFile202312061352.mp4 due to FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
```

**Details:**

I am creating executable file using following command:

```
pyinstaller cli.py \
  --onefile \
  --add-binary /Users/<machineUser>/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/ffmpeg:bin
```

The code that uses `ffmpeg` is not authored by me. And I would like to keep that part the same.

When I run from command line while `conda` environment is active I can successfully run it as `python` (or perhaps `anaconda`) knows where the binaries are. I have a pretty empty `cli.py`. That seems to be the entry point and I hope if it is possible I can set the `bin` directory's path there ...

I am able to successfully run the application like following:

```
(my_env) machineUser folder % "dist/cli_mac_001202312051431" ./testFile202312061352.mp4
```

I would like to run like following :

```
(base) machineUser folder % "dist/cli_mac_001202312051431" ./testFile202312061352.mp4
```

I would like to keep the world out side my executable's tmp folder the same. I would not want to change something that will be "left behind" after the exec is terminated.

**Question:**

Can some one please mention how to modify the `pyinstaller` command or what to change in `cli.py` to achieve it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with spec file? At least with those file I am able to perform the operation you want to achieve.
Also check my example below, based on the information, provided here

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html

**Minimal example**

The following example simply calls ffmpeg via subprocess and shows the provided help. All provided files are relative to each other. Finally, to compile the executable, run

```
pyinstaller specfile.spec
```

**main.py**

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

# check if run as script or exe --> https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    ROOT = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# set path of ffmpeg...
ffmpeg = os.path.join(ROOT, "ffmpeg.exe")
# ... and run the tool
subprocess.run([ffmpeg, "-h"])

input("press any key to close the app")
```

**specfile.spec**

```
import os
import PyInstaller.config
import sys

# how to add data to pyinstaller exe: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

launch_script = "main.py"
exe_name = "main.exe"

# path and stuff
ROOT = os.path.dirname(PyInstaller.config.CONF["spec"])

a = Analysis([os.path.join(ROOT, launch_script)],
             # extend search path
             pathex=[ROOT],
             binaries=[],
             datas = [("ffmpeg.exe", ".")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,cipher=None)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=exe_name,
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True)
```

Comment: I am open to changing spec file. 
But this example assumes that I (my authored code is calling ffmpeg). 
I basically import another library let's call it FFMPEGCaller. 
ffmpeg is required by FFMPEGCaller. 
I am merely packaging all of it together as an executable. 
subprocess.run([ffmpeg, "-h"]) seems to suggest that I should make this call. 
Is there a way that I just append path to temporary directory where the myProject's executable is extracted there ffmpeg executable will be present. 
And FFMPEGCaller library should use ffmpeg from there ...

Comment: "Is there a way that I just append path to temporary directory where the myProject's" --> This is where the MEIPASS  variable should be used for. As mentioned above, check this link here https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html. It is important to understand, that pyinstaller extracts its files to C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEIxxx where MEIxxx will differ from each executation. This folder contains also the extracted data. To refer to the path, use, the MEIPASS variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
pyinstaller cli.py \
  --onefile \
  --name cli_mac_exec \
  --add-data "FFMPEGCaller/assets/*":FFMPEGCaller/assets \
  --add-binary /Users/<machineUser>/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/ffmpeg:bin \
  --add-binary /Users/<machineUser>/anaconda3/envs/my_env/bin/ffprobe:bin
```

This should create almost correct `*.spec` file.

If needed add `import sys ; sys.setrecursionlimit(sys.getrecursionlimit() * 5)`  as the first line in the spec file. And then run:

`pyinstaller cli_mac_exec.spec`

This should create an `exec` file that should contain all ffmpeg related libraries.

And in `cli.py`

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # determine if application is a script file or frozen exe
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + resource_path("bin")
    
    cli()
```

The modification to path will not be persisted. So, this code must run on each execution.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741/5462398